# How to achieve div overlapped to another div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I achieve a `<div>` overlap so that the div `#inner-block` us in the foreground?

```css
#block-1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: #999;
  z-index: 1;
}

#inner-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #777;
  z-index: 100;
}

#block-2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
  background-color: #666;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="block-1">
  <div id="inner-block"></div>
</div>
<div id="block-2"></div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean `in the foreground`? Small block to be on top of the bigger one?

Comment: I don't think that is possible in the current setup, because the `z-index` of the parent of `#inner-block` is lower than `#block-2`. Can the elements be moved?

Comment: A simple solution would e just to move the inner block to be the child of the block-2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be to update your HTML like so:

```
<div id="block-1">
  <div id="inner-block"></div></div>
  <div id="block-2">
</div>
```

This works because it ensures that the ordering of `block-2` and `inner-block` is relative to a common parent; `block-1`:

```css
#block-1
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: #999;
  z-index: 1;
}
#inner-block
{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #777;
  z-index: 100;
}
#block-2
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
  background-color: #666;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="block-1">
  <div id="inner-block"></div>
  <div id="block-2"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `z-index` from `#bloc-1`. This will make `.inner-block` to belong to the same stacking context of `#bloc-1` and not the one created by `#bloc-1`.

> For those with 'z-index: auto', treat the element as if it created a
>   new stacking context, but any positioned descendants and descendants
>   which actually create a new stacking context should be considered part
>   **of the parent stacking context, not this new one**.<sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#painting-order)</sup>

This means that the 3 divs will belong to the same stacking context thus we can have any order we want

```css
#block-1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: #999;
}

#inner-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #777;
  z-index: 100;
}

#block-2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
  background-color: #666;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="block-1">
  <div id="inner-block"></div>
</div>
<div id="block-2"></div>
```